# How to get newly added elements from the List?

Tags: c#, webforms

I have a list called orders. 
These orders are coming from the database.

I want to identify newly added orders.

Bigger picture : 
Users add orders on a page. Orders are saved in DB and immediately displayed on the page using SignalR. 
I want to identify newly added orders so I can add color to them.

Currently, I take every order at once. Without identifying which one is the new one.

```
        ListSingleton.ClearLists();
        List<Order> orders = OrderManager.GetOrders();

        Dictionary<string, List<Order>> dictionary = ListSingleton.GetSpecificOrders(orders);
        Dictionary<string, List<Order>>.Enumerator enumerator = dictionary.GetEnumerator();

        foreach (KeyValuePair<string, List<vOrder>> entry in dictionary)
        {
            enumerator.MoveNext();
            KeyValuePair<string, List<vOrder>> currentElement = enumerator.Current;
            Notifications.Push(currentElement);
        }
```

I could take new order if I sorted orders table by Id and taking the one with the biggest value. But, in my case many users may add orders simultaneously. In which case, I will be unable to color each of them.

What would be an optimal way to identify new orders?

Comment: How do you know which orders are new? Do you have a tick implemented for each customer or a flag?

Comment: You can add a column on DB like Notify default true, and when notified set the bool to False

Comment: @mb14 SignalR takes orders from DB every second. If anything new is added it gets displayed.

Comment: @GugaTodua If you do not want to add a column, you can either check between OrderManager.GetOrders(); and orders before clear lists: any new element has to be notified

Comment: @GugaTodua Clearly you need a `IsNew` property in the `Order` entity which will always be `true` for newly added orders and which becomes `false` whenever you consider an order to be old in your workflow. The boolean value should be stored in the database as a column of the orders' table. You can show orders in different colors based on that value.